# Which Signals require impedance matching?

Tags: uart, impedance-matching, controlled-impedance

There are two types of connections in PCB.

1. Which are in between the PCB.(e.g- A SD card is connected near to Controller)
2. One is going out through some connectors.(Some UART or SPI going out through connector.)

   **My question is that both types of signals require impedance matching. Or just connection which are going outside PCB through wires require impedance matching.**

Comment: The main question is not within \ without but length of wire vs. frequency. The longer the wire & the higher the frequency the more you need impedance matching. Half the time a resistor in parallel with the input of the next stage is all you really need (i.e. a 100 ohm resistor in parallel with the relatively high impedance input of the next stage). Also, in digital below 25 mhz, you're probably fine without worrying about it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your categorization is irrelevant to the problem.

What's relevant is the question of whether the wavelength of all relevant signal components are large compared to the conductors involved.

So, yes, most high-spead signals you'll find on a PCB itself need impedance matched traces. Same goes for high-speed signals leaving the PCB.

Low-speed signals and power don't need impedance matching. Neither on PCB, nor off-PCB.